# How to compute the words given in a dict and compute if the word is on a premium tile?

Tags: python, arrays

I am currently working on a project that computes the score in a scrabble game. I am stuck on the part that could calculate the points of a word and compute if the word is on the premium tile. This is the code I have done so far

```
words_dict = {'CART': [(6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5)], 'THIEF': [(6, 5), (7, 5), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 5)], 'HORN': [(7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8)]}
```

Next to the words are the coordinates for every word that was found in a numpy array.

```
premium_tiles = [[ 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3 ],
                     [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ],
                     [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
                     [ 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ],
                     [ 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ],
                     [ 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
                     [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ],
                     [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 ],
                     [ 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3 ]]
```

On this array are points that I need to calculate the points in a word. The expected that I want is for example in CART since I made an array which look like this.

```
points = {
                'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3,
                'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2,
                'H': 4, 'I': 1, 'J': 8, 'K': 5,
                'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1,
                'P': 3, 'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1,
                'T': 1, 'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, 'X': 8,
                'Y': 4, 'Z': 10, '#': 0
            }
```

I've tried to do code but I can't seem to make it work. This is the code that I have done so far.

```
for key,value in words_dict.items():
    for keys in key:
        if len(keys) == 1: 
           for i,j in value:
               if keys == key[m+1]:
                  sum1 += premium_tiles[i][j]*points[keys]
                  print(sum1)


    sumsOfwords.append(sum1)
    print(sumsOfwords)
```

In C=3, A=1, R=1, and T=1, then it will go to the premium tiles to multiply each letter in a specified coordinate. Example the coordinates in the cart is [(6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5)] it will go to the array premium tiles and multiply the letters which C=3x2, A=1x1, R=1x1, and T=1x1. CART =(3x2+1x1+1x1+1x1) which is equal to 9. Can someone help pls? I am in need desperately.

[image: Not displaying]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this but it appears to me that you have extra blocks that don't make sense.

```
sumsOfwords = []
for key, value in words_dict.items():
    sum1 = 0
    for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(value):
        sum1 += premium_tiles[i][j] * points[key[idx]]

    # the multiplier loop goes here
    # don't combine it with the prior loop

    print(sum1)

    sumsOfwords.append(sum1)

print(sumsOfwords)
```

On the double and triple squares: With another table like `premium_tiles` that has 1 on every normal square and 2 and 3 on the double and triples.

The code would look like this:

```
for i, j in value:
    if not used[i][j]:
       sum1 *= mult[i][j]
       used[i][j] = True
```

where `used` and `mult` are tables like `premium_tiles` except that `used` starts out full of `False` and `mult` has 1 anywhere there isn't a 2 or 3.

> How can I count the points if the words are the same?

The issue there is that words_dict need to change from a dictionary to a list of tuples `[(word, [position])]` as a dictionary only permits one entry per key.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187806/discussion-on-answer-by-dan-d-how-to-compute-the-words-given-in-a-dict-and-comp). Please be sure to incorporate any useful information back into the original answer.